# Kendo UI data.model.set fail with custom validation

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo data grid as shown below:

```
$("#Grid").kendoGrid({
        save: function (data) {
            if (data.values.UnitPrice !== undefined) {
                if(data.values.UnitPrice == null || data.values.UnitPrice == 0){
                    data.model.set("EstimatedItemCost", 0);
                }
                else{
                    console.log(data.values.UnitPrice * data.model.Quantity);
                    var test = data.model.set("EstimatedItemCost", data.values.UnitPrice * data.model.Quantity);
                }
            }
            this.refresh();
        },
....//other config
```

and it's using data source with a little custom validation

```
 var tdata = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    schema: {
        model: {
            fields: {
                UnitPrice: { 
                    type: "number", 
                    validation:{
                        min: 0, 
                        conditionalRequired: function(input){
                            if(input.is("[name='UnitPrice']")){
                                input.attr("data-conditionalRequired-msg", "Unit Price is required");

                                //Some logic, without changing the result, simply return true
                               return true;
                            }
                        }
                    },

                },
                EstimatedItemCost: { type: "number" },
                Remarks: { type: "string" }
            }
        }
    },
```

Okay, Now here is the description of the problem:

`data.model.set("EstimatedItemCost", data.values.UnitPrice * data.model.Quantity);`
does not set the value of `EstimatedItemCost`, it remains 0 anyway.

i.e.: `console.log(data.values.UnitPrice * data.model.Quantity);` has show a valid number like 200, but the value of `EstimatedItemCost` is still 0 after the `set()`.

With further drilling, I found it is due to the existence of the custom validation in the datasource
`conditionalRequired`, after I remove it, everything goes fine!

But I really need the validation logic, while setting the value of model explicitly.

Can anyone tell me what is the cause of this problem, and how can I solve it?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

**EDIT1:**

Adding a few console log, I found that after the `set()`, the custom validation function **runs once again! (and fail)**, I don't know what trigger the validation once again though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your validation is wrong , it should look like this

```
var tdata = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    schema: {
        model: {
            fields: {
                UnitPrice: { 
                    type: "number", 
                    validation:{
                        min: 0, 
                        conditionalRequired: function(input){
                            if(input.is("[name='UnitPrice']")){
                                input.attr("data-conditionalRequired-msg", "Unit Price is required");

                                //Some logic, without changing the result, simply return true
                               return true;
                            }else{
                               return false;
                            }

                          return true;
                        }
                    },

                },
                EstimatedItemCost: { type: "number" },
                Remarks: { type: "string" }
            }
        }
    },
```

basically the conditionalRequired will run for all your model items , so u should return true if(input.is("[name='UnitPrice']")) not what you need to validate.

Comment: Thanks...I work around it meanwhile so I could not test if it is correct but yes I think it is the cause of the problem! i.e.: I give you an accept ! :)